# Java AES security implementation

Tags: java, security, spring-security

I want to encrypt a String to interger with fix lenght, How can I do that in Java.
tring to implement AES Algorithm but the out is a special Character and not a number.

```
          String text = "Test TEST";         
          String key = "deadbeefbeefdead"; // 128 bit key
         // Create key and cipher
         Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
         // encrypt the text
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
         byte[] encrypted = cipher..doFinal(text.getBytes());
         System.err.println(new String(encrypted));
         // decrypt the text
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
         String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
         System.err.println(decrypted
```

);

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but here is some information:

1. Encryption generates a sequence of 8-bit bytes, not characters, not all 8-bit bytes are printable characters or even characters in most encodings. Generally if you require a printable string the encrypted data is Base64 or hex encoded. Each encrypted byte can be considered a uint8_t "integer".
2. AES is a block cipher, it takes 16-byte chunks and outputs 16-byte chunks. If the input is not a multiple of the block size padding (extra bytes) must be added to the input prior to encryption. "Bhaumik Patel" is 13 bytes so 3 bytes must be added prior to encryption and removed after decryption. Most block encryption libraries include a padding option, generally PKCS#7 (PKCS#5) but occasionally null padding.
3. There is also a mode,most commonally ECB (not secure) and CBC. In the case of CBC there is also a block-sized iv (initialization vector), generally a random sequence of bytes.

Unfortunately, encryption alone is generally only *part* of a secure solution.

Edit: The question text input was changed from "Bhaumik Patel" to ""Test TEST"".

Comment: Hi Zaph,  Thank you for your replay, Based on my requirement I need a number so  I used an AES encryption and converted to hex , from hex to number but the number is too big like either 39 digit, till 156 digit. is there any way I can reduce it so that it can reduce i number I want.. Thank you in advance you help will be appreciated !!!

Comment: Encryption will not reduce the number of bits, for that you need to use a compression algorithm such as zip. If the input is <= 64 bits you can encrypt in CRT mode which is not block based, it is however easy to make CTR mode insecure.

Comment: Is there a limit on the text to be encrypted to <. 64-bits?

Comment: Max String limit is 20 Char, 160 bites. There is not limit to encrypte text to < 64 bits. but I am sure it is always more.  I am trying to reduce number to as less digit as possible.

Comment: Then you will not be able to fit the encrypted data into a 64-bit integer. You need to be able to fit the unencrypted data into 8 bytes.

Comment: // Performs Encryption
         public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception 
         {
                 Key key = generateKey();
                 Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
                 
                 chiper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                 byte[] encVal = chiper.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
                 
// converting byte array to Hex
// cenverting hex to bigInteger
// The result is coming 39 digit number minimum. is there any way I can reduce it ?
                }

Comment: Encryption works on bytes, at a minimum the unencrypted source must be no larger than the encrypted result. If you want to fit the result into a 64-bit unsigned integer (8-bytes) the input to the encryption must be 8-bytes or less. Get the input down to 8-bytes then work on the encryption. Encryption does not compress data. Also re-evaluate why you are restricting the output to an 8-byte integer.